# Node.js and Mongoose regex query on multiple fields

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to query multiple fields using the same regular expression for both. In this query, I would like to accept a single text input and check both the firstName and lastName fields for results. I can query a single field just fine using the regex function in the mongoose documentation, but the syntax for an 'or' clause is giving me trouble.

```
var re = new RegExp(req.params.search, 'i');

app.User.find().or([{ 'firstName': { $regex: re }}, { 'lastName': { $regex: re }}]).sort('title', 1).exec(function(err, users) {
    res.json(JSON.stringify(users));
});
```

(I'm running mongoose 2.7.1 on node.js 0.6.12)

Comment: Syntax looks ok; can you expand on the trouble it's giving you?

Comment: Oh darn. It was some bad data. It turns out that does indeed work fine.

Comment: What if you had a person named "Joe Smith" and and someone searched for "Joe S" - no results?

Comment: Good question. A much more robust solution would be needed for partial keyword matches.

Comment: @MikeCauser: Any idea how to write search query in case if someone searches for "Joe S" and get records like "Joe Smith" in result. I need to implement it but facing trouble.

Comment: Check out the MDN article on Regular Expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: `.` matches any character. `.*` matches any character zero or more times. `.+` matches any character one or more times. `^` is the start of the string and `$` is the end.

Comment: For a partial match try `var re = new RegExp('^.*' + req.params.search + '.*$', 'i');`

Comment: For a starts with match try `var re = new RegExp('^' + req.params.search + '.*$', 'i');`

Comment: @MikeCauser using your regular expressions does not return any result in case of "Joe S". it should return "Joe Smith".

Comment: This query won't return the result "Joe Smith" when you search "Joe S" because the query is comparing the `req.query.search` string to `firsName` **OR** `lastName` therefore "Joe S" is not equal to "Joe" **OR** "Smith".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code above works fine for a query on multiple fields. Turns out I had some bad data.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/#mongodb-expression-exp.-function) that allows you to concatenate multiple fields and match their combined value against your regular expression.

```
const { search } = req.params;
var regex = new RegExp(`.*${search}.*`, 'i');

app.User.find({
    $expr: {
        $function: {
            body: `function(firstName, lastName) { return (firstName+' '+lastName).match(${regex}) }`,                        
            args: ['$firstName', '$lastName'],                
            lang: "js"
        }
    }
})
.exec((err, users) => {
    res.json(JSON.stringify(users));
});
```