# Removing single quation mark, javascript

Tags: mongodb

I need to remove single quotation marks from

```
var test = '\/'+val.text+'\/i';
```

in order to do a mongodb search like db.document.find({field:test})
That is, If val.text is 'hello', the find should be

```
db.document.find({field:/hello/i})
```

and not

```
db.document.find({field:'/hello/i'})
```

which wont find any field with the substring 'hello'
How do I do that without using eval(test) ?

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? It is hard to understand what do you need

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874709/converting-user-input-string-to-regular-expression

Comment: duplicate, more or less : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725708/node-js-and-mongoose-regex-query-on-multiple-fields

Answer (score 1):

```
// This should do it:
var test = new RegExp(val.text, "i");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val.text.replace("'", "");
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: Ah, I now understand what you want. You want to build a Regexp literal, and not a String. Forsvunnets answer should do what you want!