# Mongoose: query full name with regex

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following code to search a user either by first or last name:

```
var re = new RegExp(req.params.search, 'i');

User.find()
    .or([{ firstName: re }, { lastName: re }])
    .exec(function(err, users) {
        res.json(JSON.stringify(users));
    });
```

It works well if `search` equals `'John'` or `'Smith'`, but not for `'John Sm'`.

Any clue how to accomplish this kind of query?

Thanks!

**Disclaimer**: This question originally appeared on the comments of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725708/node-js-and-mongoose-regex-query-on-multiple-fields) 3 years ago and remains unanswered. I'm starting a new thread because 1) It wasn't the main question and 2) I consider this is interesting enough to have its own thread

EDIT:

Suppose the database contains two records: `John Smith` and `John Kennedy`.

- Querying `John` should return both `John Smith` and `John Kennedy`
- Querying `John Sm` should return only `John Smith`

Comment: Well, the problem is that your name fields are separate. In this case, applying the same regex to both fields will not result the results that you want. The regex needs to be applied to the same field with the complete name.

Comment: I understand. This brought me the question if I could query virtual fields in mongoose, and I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452795/sorting-by-virtual-field-in-mongodb-mongoose) where the answer is no. I guess I will make my own implementation, a post-query filter and submit the answer. Thank you ZeMoon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Separate the search term by words, and separate them using an alternation operator ('|').

```
var terms = req.params.search.split(' ');

var regexString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++)
{
    regexString += terms[i];
    if (i < terms.length - 1) regexString += '|';
}

var re = new RegExp(regexString, 'ig');
```

For the input `'John Smith'`, this will create a regex which looks like `/John|Smith/ig`. This will return true for individual words as well as work when the input is just `'John Sm'`

You can [play around](http://regexr.com/3b1hu) with this regex to get one more suited to your needs.

EDIT:

The problem here is that your name fields are separate. In this case, applying the same regex to both fields will not result the results that you want. The regex needs to be applied to the same field with the complete name.

A possible solution is using aggregation:

```
User.aggregate()
    .project({fullName: {$concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName']}})
    .match({fullName: re})
```

Comment: I tried that. But it also returns `John Kennedy` with the query `John Sm`

Comment: I updated the answer with two test cases. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but it returns empty results with just `John`, since both query conditions must be satisfied. I expect both `John Smith` and `John Kennedy` to be returned. This is for an autocompletion/search field.

Comment: Wow. It worked as a charm. This actually simplified my code A LOT. Huge thanks!

Comment: Could you supply whole code because `User.aggregate().project({fullName: {$concat: ['$firstName', ' ', '$lastName']}}).match({fullName: re}).exec(callback);` is not working for me.

Comment: instead of for loop terms.split(' ').join('|')