# MongoDB: Filter Fullname by combination of firstname and lastname

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Sample doc is given below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a61cbc677366f5e0cdc95db"),
    "Indvl" : {
        "Info" : {
            "lastNm" : "ALEX",
            "firstNm" : "BOB",
            "midNm" : "Y",
        }       
    }
}
```

Now we use the following query to do a search using name.
we have to do the same for the combination of `lastNm`,  `firstNm`, `midNm`

```
db.getCollection("MyCOL").find({ "Indvl.Info.firstNm":{$regex: "al" , $options:"i"})
```

***How can we do this?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: query full name with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341341/mongoose-query-full-name-with-regex)

Comment: @Veeram its not a duplicate , i have more filters to add to the same query so i cant use functions, aggregate.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify.

Comment: @Veeram thanks for not helping and ruining it.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.MyCOL.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                name: {
                    $concat: ['$Indvl.Info.lastNm', ' ', '$Indvl.Info.firstNm', ' ', '$Indvl.Info.midNm']
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
                name: /al/i
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answered for me:

```
db.MyCOL
    .aggregate(
        [ { $project: {fullName: { $concat: ['$Indvl.Info.firstNm', ' ', '$Indvl.Info.lastNm']}} },
          { $match: {fullName: /alex bob/} }
        ]
);
```